# adding rows after for loop in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Hi I am new to python if I want to add row to an empty matrix after for loop in python how would I be able to do so. This is how I do it in Matlab.

```
n = 10000;
tic
A = [];
for i = 1:n
  Ai = rand(1,3);
  A = [A;Ai];
end
toc
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

Add a list to an empty matrix as a row where `[i for i in range(4)]` will give you a list `[0,1,2,3]`

```
#empty matrix
mat = []
mat.append([i for i in range(4)])
print mat

#output
[[0,1,2,3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use append to add rows at the end of an array:

```
a = []
for i in range(10):
    a.append([1,2,3])

print a
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner:

```
import random

matrix = [[random.randint(1, 3) for _ in range(10)]]
```

I wonder why would you need a one-row "matrix", as opposed to just a list of random numbers.

If you want a matrix with 1000 identical rows, create a row and add it 1000 times.

```
row = [random.randint(1, 3) for _ in range(10)]
matrix = [row for _ in range(1000)]
```

Or a funny syntax-sugared version:

```
matrix = [row] * 1000
```

Please note that the matrix will have 1000 references to *the same* row, not 1000 different copies of the row. If you mutate any value in any row, it will affect *every* row.

If you want a mutable matrix *initially* filled with 1000 identical rows, make a copy of the row each time:

```
matrix = [list(row) for _ in range(1000)]
```

Each invocation of `list` creates a new list filled with numbers from `row`.

Comment: This is what I want to do I want to create a random one by three row vector and add it to an empty matrix a thousand time...to make it a 1000X3 matrix

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `numpy.random`

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.randint(1,4, size=(1000, 3))
```

and `A` should be the matrix you want.

For example,

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(1,4, size=(10, 3))
```

a looks like:

```
array([[1, 3, 3],
       [3, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 1],
       [3, 2, 3],
       [2, 1, 2],
       [3, 3, 2],
       [2, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a = []
for i in range(2):
    ai = np.random.rand(1,3)
    a.append([ai])
print a
```